# Plotting SMA and MA of RSI together

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to plot an SMA and an SMA of RSI together in one indicator window. Here is my script (based on another script that plotted 2 MAs of RSI, I just changed `ma2` from `basis` to `close`):

```
study(title="MAofRSI / MA", shorttitle="MAoRSI / MA", overlay=false)

basis = rsi(close, input(14))

ma1 = sma(basis, input(2))
ma2 = sma(close,input(13))

oversold = input(30)
overbought = input(70)

plot(ma1, title="MA of RSI", color=teal)
plot(ma2, title="SMA", color=orange)

obhist = ma1 >= overbought ? ma1 : overbought
oshist = ma1 <= oversold ? ma1 : oversold

plot(obhist, title="Overbought Highlight", style=histogram, color=maroon, histbase=overbought)
plot(oshist, title="Oversold Highlight", style=histogram, color=green, histbase=oversold)

i1 = hline(oversold, title="Oversold Level", color=green)
i2 = hline(overbought, title="Overbought Level", color=maroon)

fill(i1, i2, color=olive, transp=70)

hline(50, title="50 Level", color=black)
```

However, my new SMA is just a flat line in the bottom:

[image]

I was hoping to see them interact together, crossing over one another in a beautiful dance. Obviously something is amiss with my methods here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your moving averages are based on different scales:

`ma2` is based on close price of the current ticker,
and `ma1` is based on your `rsi` function.

While the rsi is a bounded (0,100) oscillator and the moving average of rsi could not leave those bounds, MA based on current ticker's price has no bounds (0, +infinity) and they could not be compared on the same scale.

In pinescript you cannot plot at different scales (rsi's and ticker's) at the same time, only one to select. So you have to plot SMA of close as a separate script on the chart's scale, or invent a boundaries logic and scale to the rsi's Y axis.

Comment: I see ok, that makes sense. I am trying to catch the divergence between the MA and the RSI more clearly... Any ideas?? :)

Comment: Tradingview provide a built-in divergence detector (pine-editor -> open -> new default built-in script -> divergence indicator). By default it compares the the ticker's OHLC with rsi. You can customize the script and change the OHLC values to MA or any other series to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks e2e4, would you care to turn that into an answer with an example of how to incorporate the MA into the built-in indicator?